# Overlay covers the div - keep fonts white

Tags: css, brightness

I trying to change the brightess of a div (not only an image brightness). Generaly there is an image in a div, description and caption, the main div background color is white. I want to show ovarlay div onmouse hover. Idea is to cover main  div with overlay div. But now I getting only the image brightness change together with fonts. What I want to achieve is to cover the hole div while keeping font’s white z.

When I add a thumbnail brightness effect it also influence the fonts to became darker. how to do that keeping fonts white.

col-sm-6, caption, thumbnail classes are defined by bootstrap.

The code of:

```
                     <div  class="hovereffect thumbnail Staffinview1 delay1s">
                      <img src="./images/photo.jpg">

                      <div class="overlay">
                        <?php echo Person_description; ?>
                      </div>
                    
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Name Surname</h3>
                      </div>

                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

The css code:

```
                 .thumbnail:hover {
                     transition:         all 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                    -moz-transition:    all 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                    -o-transition:      all 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                    -ms-transition:     all 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    }
                    
                    .hovereffect {
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                      float: left;
                      overflow: hidden;
                      position: relative;
                      text-align: center;
                      cursor: default;
                    }

                    .hovereffect .overlay {
                      position: absolute;
                      overflow: hidden;
                      width: 80%;
                      height: 80%;
                      left: 10%;
                      top: 10%;
                      border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
                      border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
                      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
                      transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
                      -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
                      -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
                      transform: scale(0,1);
                      color: #fff;
                    }

                    .hovereffect:hover .overlay {
                      opacity: 1;
                      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
                      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                      -ms-transform: scale(1);
                      transform: scale(1);

                    }


                    .hovereffect img {
                      display: block;
                      position: relative;
                      -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
                      transition: all 0.35s;
                    }

                    .hovereffect:hover img{
                      filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" />                                                                        </feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter');
                      filter: brightness(0.3);
                      -webkit-filter: brightness(0.3);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe You are trying to achieve a mask
You can use `z-index` property and `postion:absolute` for that overlay div

css rule

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Snippet below

```css
.thumbnail:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease - in -out;
  - moz - transition: all 0.5s ease - in -out;
  - webkit - transition: all 0.5s ease - in -out;
  - o - transition: all 0.5s ease - in -out;
  - ms - transition: all 0.5s ease - in -out;
  box - shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hovereffect {
  width: 100 %;
  height: 100 %;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text - align: center;
  cursor: default;
}
.hovereffect.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80 %;
  height: 80 %;
  left: 10 %;
  top: 10 %;
  border - bottom: 1px solid# FFF;
  border - top: 1px solid# FFF;
  - webkit - transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit - transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  - webkit - transform: scale(0, 1);
  - ms - transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  color: #fff;
}
.hovereffect:hover.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  - webkit - transform: scale(1);
  - ms - transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  - webkit - transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.overlay:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="hovereffect thumbnail Staffinview1 delay1s">
  <img src="./images/photo.jpg">

  <div class="overlay">
    <?php echo Person_description; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Name Surname</h3>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yes but see whats heppen when you place mous over - Name and surname are not black as at he begining they are also change the colour. I want to keep the font kolor w/o any change..

Comment: The font color does not change..it remains the same..It is just whenever You are  overlapping different colors with different opacity your display blends those colors...I think for your situation..you can simply change the background of the main container on hover instead of overlapping the main div.This will get you what you want

Comment: - Yes it the best solution, Thanks